# Make find show slash after directories?

Tags: find

How can I make the find command show a slash after directories? For example, I want `dir` to show up as `dir/` instead of `dir`. I'm using `find . -print`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Portably:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"' {} \; -or -print
```

If you're willing to list directories and files separately (you can merge the output by sorting):

```
{ find . -type d -print | sed 's!$!/!'; find . \! -type d; } | sort
```

With GNU find, see [Shawn J. Goff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/make-find-show-slash-after-directories/4849#4849).

If you're willing to risk non-printable characters being mangled even when not outputting to a terminal, see [ddeimeke's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/make-find-show-slash-after-directories/4856#4856).

In zsh: `print -rl -- **/*(DM)` (`D` to include dot files, `M` to add a `/` after directories)

Comment: The first command didn't print trailing slashes for me, but the second one does.

Answer (score 21):

```bsh
find . \( -type d -printf "%p/\n" , ! -type d -print \)
```

This uses the `printf` command to format directory names and standard print for the rest.

Comment: I continue to be amazed at the flexibility of find.

Comment: Note that `-printf` is specific to GNU find.

Comment: Nice answer. I like how `find`'s positional arguments allow it to do advanced output like this. However, note that without the spaces around the comma, it will not work.

Comment: Based on this answer and Gilles', I came up with the following simplified version: `find . -type d -printf '%p/\n' -or -print`

Answer (score 10):

Maybe

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 ls -Fd
```

is an option as well.

From a Solaris man page:

> -F Marks directories with a  trailing  slash  (/), doors  with  a  trailing
>   greater-than sign (>), executable
>   files with a trailing asterisk  (*),
>   FIFOs  with  a  trailing vertical bar
>   (|), symbolic links with a trailing
>   "at" sign (@),  and AF_UNIX  address
>   family sockets with a trailingequals
>   sign  (=).  Follows  symlinks  named 
>   as operands.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for the "d" ;-)

Comment: this increases the amount of syscalls

Answer (score 0):

I want the trailing /, but not the asterisks. Also one can omit the -print:

```
find . | xargs ls -Fd | sed -e "s/*//"
```

Comment: You may want to use `ls -p -d` rather than `ls` with `-F` and the `sed`.  The `-p` option to `ls` is a standard POSIX option.

Comment: `tree -ifF --noreport` instead `find | xargs`

Comment: You should never use xargs without -0. Do this instead: `find . -print0 | xargs -0` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I finally went with [code]find ${DIR} -type f[/code] and extract the directories in Java code.