# Using expressions and actions with 'find -o'

Tags: find

According to `find`'s man page, OR is used with expressions:

```
expr1 -o expr2
              Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
```

Why then does it also work with actions such as `-print`, as in this example?

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"' {} \; -or -print
```

(from [Make find show slash after directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4847)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actions are [expressions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html#EXPRESSION) too; they are expressions which have a side-effect. ([POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) doesn’t even mention actions.)

In `-exec`’s case, the value of the expression reflects the status of the command which is run: if it succeeds, indicated by an exit code of 0, the expression’s value is true, otherwise it’s false. So

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"' {} \; -or -print
```

recurses from the current directory; for files which are directories, it executes `sh` to run `printf` (adding a forward slash after the directory); for everything else, it runs `find`’s `print` action. The `-or` is a disjunction between `-type d -exec ...` and `-print`; the value which matters here is `-type d`’s, not `-exec`’s.

In more detail, `find`’s precedence rules mean that

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"' {} \; -or -print
```

can be written more explicitly as

```
find . \( -type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"' {} \; \) -or -print
```

The expressions `-or` joins are respectively

```
-type d -exec sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"' {} \;
```

and

```
-print
```

The whole set of expressions is evaluated for every file (in the general meaning of the term, *i.e.* including directories etc.), starting from the left:

1. `-type d` evaluates to true if the current file is a directory, false otherwise.
2. `-exec ...` is evaluated if the previous expression was true, so if the current file is a directory; its evaluation involves running `sh -c 'printf "%s/\n" "$0"'` with the current file as argument, and the result is true if `sh` exits with status 0, false otherwise.
3. `-print` is evaluated if the result of the previous expression (both `-type` and `-exec`) is **false**, *i.e.* either the current file is not a directory, or it is but `sh` failed.

Comment: So does this mean that expression 1 is evaluated for everything, and then expression 2 is evaluated only for things not matched by expression 1? I assumed that if expression 1 matched anything at all, expression 2 would be ignored.

Comment: Expression 1 is evaluated for everything, and expression 2 is evaluated whenever expression 1 returns false. Expression 1 returns false for files which don’t match `type d`, and would also return false if the `exec` failed for whatever reason. So the effect is indeed that expression 2 is evaluated whenever expression 1 fails to match.

Answer (score 3):

A small `-o` completely switches the output; there are two files (containing "111" and "2 2"), and two uncattable directories matching 'test*'

```
$ find .  -name 'test*'  \(  -exec cat {} \;   -print \) 2>/dev/null
1111 111 11111
./test
2 2 2 2
./test2


$ find .  -name 'test*'  \(  -exec cat {} \;  -o  -print \) 2>/dev/null
./testdir
./testdir2
1111 111 11111
2 2 2 2
```

The first (implicit `-a`) does the `-print` after each successful `-exec`. For dirs, the error message is redirected, and the -print is not "evaluated" - the logical AND-chain is broken.

The second ("cat OR print") prints on failure only.

The example for prune is hidden in man find; I had a hard time understanding it.

```
find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
```

These AND-OR-lists are tricky, and then also precedence matters, and then you soon need these nice `\(parens\)`. Find makes ugly command lines, but nice queries!